# Use escape char in spring jpa native query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have below native query where I want to escape underscore(_) so it wont act as a literal in like search

PS: this is just a part of query not full

```
 @RestResource(path = "findLatestEmployeeByNameExactMatch", rel = "findLatestEmployeeByNameExactMatch")
 @Query(value = "select e from Employee e " +
        " WHERE :name IS NULL OR upper(e.name) LIKE upper(:name) " +
        " AND e.latestProject = (select MAX(an.latestProject) from Employee an where upper(an.name) = upper(a.name))")
Employee findEmployeeByName(@Param("name") String name);
```

Employee table

```
name     latest_project
John_X   123
John_X   124
John-X   123
John-X   124
```

The current api returns two records `John_X 124` and `John-X 124` when searched for `John_X` as `_` is considered literal. I want to escape underscore and only return `John_X 124`

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

`LIKE` queries don't interpret the left side as `LIKE` expressions. Only the right side of the `LIKE` query is interpreted like this. So, you need to change the `:name` part which can be done easily using a `default` method:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT e from employee e WHERE :name IS NULL OR upper(e.name) LIKE :name")
Employee findEmployeeByNameEscaped(@Param("name") String name);

default Employee findEmployeeByName(String name){
    return findEmployeeByNameEscaped(name.toUpperCase().replace("_","\\_");
}
```

You can then just normally use `findEmployeeByName` which will call `findEmployeeByNameEscaped` with the correct parameter.

#### Update

Since you don't need (and don't want) the features of `LIKE`, you should use `=` instead:

```java
 @Query(value = "SELECT e from employee e WHERE :name IS NULL OR upper(e.name) = upper(:name)")
Employee findEmployeeByName(@Param("name") String name);
```

(I'm using the old version of the SQL statement here as I don't feel like the new one is valid due t the `SELECT ... WHERE ... FROM ...`)

With that, you won't need to escape `_` as it will compare the strings directly insteas of matching.

Comment: this is data rest api with ```@RestResource(path = "findLatestEmployeeByNameExactMatch", rel = "findLatestEmployeeByNameExactMatch")``` and default method is not recognised if I add this to it as that will act as entry point

Comment: I get 404 for ```@RestResource(path = "findLatestEmployeeByNameExactMatch", rel = "findLatestEmployeeByNameExactMatch")
    default Employee findLatestEmployeeByNameExactMatch(@Param("name") String name) {
        return findEmployee(name.toUpperCase().replace("_","\\_"));
    }```

Comment: Can you share both the data in the DB and the search query (Ideally by editing your original question as it allows you to properly format it)?

Comment: Is there any reason you are using `LIKE` and not `=`?

Comment: What is `findEmployee` in the code you mentioned? Does it make a difference if you directly call the `default` method without the REST API/`@RestResource` i.e. just call `findEmployeeByName("John_X")`?

Comment: I think doing an eqaul makes more sense as this is a exact match. I overthought about this because all the rest custom repository methods are avaialble at ```entity/search/yourCustomerApi``` and put LIKE operator. thanks for quickly asking that question

Comment: Putting this under a custom controller instead of relying on data rest also works but we have projections that we use which default works in repository methods without needing customization

Comment: In this case, it seems like the repository method might not be the problem. Can you share the complete controller as well as the reason you need to use `LIKE` instead of `=` in your question?

Comment: I dont have a controller. This is the data rest api with `@RestRepository`. Using `LIKE` was a mistake as I thought all custom data rest api should do a search but wrong. Using `=` makes sense in the query that solve the issue